# Where is the file for the Fancy Startup Screen

Tags: start-up, help

I'm trying to find where the contents of the *GNU Emacs* buffer, aka fancy startup screen, are located on my hard drive.

`M-x eval-expression buffer-file-name` returns `nil`. The [buffer-file-name documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html) says:

> If buffer is not visiting any file, buffer-file-name returns nil.

If it is not a file then where is this text coming from? I checked the source code at https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/tree/master/doc but I didn't see anything.

Comment: The reason I want to know is that I want to open the file in a different editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text displayed on the startup screen is stored in the `fancy-startup-text` constant. You can find it using `describe-variable`. There's also the function `fancy-startup-screen`, which actually displays it.

Comment: I found that fancy-startup-text is a variable defined in ‘startup.el’. So it's not a stand-alone file in the emacs source code?

Comment: Indeed. It's just one of the things in `startup.el`. Considering the splash screen has images and clickable links, a basic format wouldn't suffice, and a separate file makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

A very interesting question!

By quickly doing a grep, I found that the splash buffer is created by the `fancy-startup-screen` function (refer to [startup.el](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/startup.el#L1948)),
it will create the `*GNU Emacs*` buffer, and then insert the splash image and text content.

Want to find out the path of the splash image?

By inspecting the code, you will find the image name by evaluating this `(fancy-splash-image-file)` function,
which is `splash.svg` on my box (`/usr/share/emacs/27.2/etc/images/splash.svg` on my linux FS.)